# method is unable to return in ruby

Tags: ruby

Below is a method which  should return true if there is an existing user (a test to happen before trying to drop user). But it is not returning anything. I

```
   def is_user?(user_name)
     puts "Checking if #{user_name} exists: "
     select_sql = <<-EOF
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM all_users
      WHERE username = upper('#{user_name}')
     EOF

    select_stmt = @conn.create_statement
    result_set = select_stmt.execute_query(select_sql)
    count = Array.new

    while(result_set.next)
      count = result_set.getInt(1)
    end
    result_set.close()
    select_stmt.close()

    if (count > 0)
       #puts "#{count}" <---- This prints 1           
       return true
    else
       return false
    end
 end
```

After creating the connection object, I am calling this method and it not returning anything. Connection has been established successfully. I tried to `return count` but it is also not returning anything. Can anyone help me find what is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: But it prints `1` when that line is uncommented? Are you sure you're handling the returned value? How are you calling this method?

Comment: Small correction: I have <code>puts "#{count}"</code> before <code>return true</code> and it is printing <code>1</code>. This is how I am calling my method: <code> conn_obj = Module1::ConnectionClass.new('host_name', '1500', 'sid', 'usr', 'pwd')</conde> and then <code> conn_obj.is_user?('username')</code>

Comment: What do you mean by 'not returning anything'? Does it return `nil`?

Comment: No, it is not returning anything. So when I call the method, it just prints "Checking if Username exists: " and exits.

Comment: So, is exiting afterwards a normal behaviour or a crash? Looks like it manages to get to the end of the method successfully if it is able to print the count.

Comment: If you are really just writing `conn_obj.is_user?('username')` by itself, then you're ignoring the return value, so how do you know whether or not it's returning anything?

Comment: So, you need to capture the returned value. Try `hereIsMyResult = conn_obj.is_user?('username')`, followed by `puts hereIsMyResult`. This will store the result and print it. Let us know what it says.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: I did the same as  you suggested. puts is printing true. Hence the function is returning correct value. That is all I needed. So is it like when I am calling a function which is not void I must capture its output in some variable or print it or use that returned value to compare? Anyways all I wanted to do is to compare the value with some other value. Thank you. That was helpful.

Comment: As a side note, your code contains a SQL injection vulnerability unless you make sure that `user_name` is properly escaped according to your SQL flavor before calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
(count > 0)
```

by itself instead of:

```
if (count > 0)
   #puts "#{count}" <---- This prints 1           
   return true
else
   return false
end
```

It does the same thing and would be idiomatic Ruby.

I'd also strongly recommend you use the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) ORM for your database connectivity needs. It's extremely well written and portable.

Once you'd established a connection to your database you could use this to replace your code:

```
def is_user?(user_name)
  DB[:users].where(:username => user_name.upcase).count > 0
end
```